# Python Dictionary iteration alternative approach?

Tags: python, dictionary

I know from other posts that you can run into all sorts of problems iterating over a dictionary. I'm trying to modify one of the columns based on the key, but it only takes the value of the last operation done so.

```
D={}
for i in range(len(countries['Country'])):
    D["output_fwd_%s" % (countries['Country'][i])]=input_fwd
```

The above works fine, and I now have keys for all the countries, which have the same data as input_fwd. I have 12 entries under countries

```
countries.head()
Out[140]: 
       Country  LHS_BumpFactor  RHS_BumpFactor
0        Japan               1               1
1  South Korea               1               1
2    Singapore               1               1
3     HongKong               1               1
4       Taiwan               1               1
```

Now, I want to alter one of the columns in each of these newly created keys

```
for i in range(len(countries['Country'])):
    D['output_fwd_%s' % (countries['Country'][i])['Country']=countries['Country'][i]
```

The above doesn't work as expected and all the keys have the same value in the Country column (which is equal to `countries['Country'][11]`)

However, `D['output_fwd_%s' % (countries['Country'][2])]['Country']=countries['Country'][2]` individually works, but if I again do 2 of those at a time:

```
D['output_fwd_%s' % (countries['Country'][1])]['Country']=countries['Country'][1]
D['output_fwd_%s' % (countries['Country'][2])]['Country']=countries['Country'][2]
```

both of the above will have the country value as `countries['Country'][2])`

```
input_fwd.head()
Out[155]: 
      CCY abc def       pqr        xyz    Country
0  USDINR    AAA    1m  0.000000  0.000000e+00  Indonesia
1  USDINR    AAA    2m  0.000002  6.000000e-07  Indonesia
2  USDINR    AAA    3m  0.000005  2.200000e-06  Indonesia
3  USDINR    AAA    4m  0.000009  6.100000e-06  Indonesia
4  USDINR    AAA    5m  0.000014  6.100000e-06  Indonesia
```

What is a smart way of achieving this pls? I will later want to concat the values in all the above keys into one single large dataframe.

Thanks vm

Comment: The code that "doesn't work as expected" seems to have mismatched brackets and quotation marks. Please paste your actual code in there.

Comment: "*I now have keys for all the countries, which have the same data as input_fwd*" - alternately, they are all bound to the exact same input_fwd object and when you change it via any name there's only one thing being changed and all of them reflect the change.

Comment: What is `input_fwd`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 sorry about that.. 
`for i in range(len(countries['Country'])):
    D['input_fwd_%s' % (countries['Country'][i])]['Country']=countries['Country'][i]`

@TessellatingHeckler input_fwd does not have the column 'Country', am adding that in the above loop which doesn't work

@juanpa.arrivillaga 

`input_fwd.head()
Out[155]: 
      CCY pqr lmn       abc        def    Country
0  USDINR    AAA    1m  0.000000  0.000000e+00  Indonesia
1  USDINR    AAA    2m  0.000002  6.000000e-07  Indonesia`

Comment: In _there_ - the question - not _here_ - the comments.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 gotcha, just did that

Comment: @spiff TessellatingHeckler diagnosed your problem correctly. Assignment does not make a copy, it assigns to the same object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  how so?  sorry i dont get it..

`for i in range(len(countries['Country'])):
    D['output_fwd_%s' % (countries['Country'][i])]['Country']=countries['Country'][i]`

in the above code, which does not work as expected, I am not calling upon input_fwd.. 

so everything done with 

`for i in range(len(countries['Country'])):
    D["output_fwd_%s" % (countries['Country'][i])]=input_fwd`

should remain as is? with teh newly formed data,  I am just trying to add a column based on an iteration

Comment: This code is needlessly complex: you can replace the first lines with: `D = dict([c, input_fwd] for c in countries['Country']])`

Comment: @NunoAndré thanks vm - would that work if input_fwd did not have a 'Country' column as well?

Comment: @spiff `input_fwd` is an object. You assign that object to different keys in your dictionary, but they point to the *same exact object*. The data isn't copied. In your second loop, you then update the contents of the same `input_fwd` object `input_fwd['Country']` with the corresponding country name from `countries`.

Comment: @spiff Are you trying to assign the value of input_fwd with the respective key in the dict? Is input_fwd a list of dicts?

Comment: @NunoAndré tried what you said.. it is indeed an elegant way of doing what I am doing in my first loop. How do I now add a column as well to the data which is the same value as the key of that block?

Edit: input_fwd is just a dataframe with 1000s of rows and 5 columns (country is not a column in it). I do not care about input_fwd anymore.. as I need the same data of input_fwd one below the other for 12 times and just have a column called country which changes each of the 12 times

Comment: @NunoAndré No, it's apparently another  `pandas.DataFrame`.  @spiff what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Whatever you're doing here is probably over-complicating things. There's almost never a reason to not use `pandas` to reshape your data and instead use a dictionary.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks a lot for your patience here.. I have a pandas.DataFrame .. input_fwd.. i want it 12 times (or as many times as the number of countries in countries['Country] )one below the other and then have another column which corresponds to each of the countries..  nothing changes in terms of the data per country.. those operations I will do later after making the large dataframe

Comment: @spiff 12 times what? Its hard to follow what you mean.

Comment: Try out with: `for k,v in countries['Country'].items():
D[k]['Country'] = v`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 

`test = pd.DataFrame()
test = [1,2,3,4,5]
num_countries = (len(countries['Country']))
new_test = test * num_countries`

Does the above help? 

After doing the above, I want to add another column to new_test which is country name as well for every [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: @NunoAndré  
`D = dict([c, input_fwd] for c in countries['Country'])

for k,v in countries['Country'].items():
    D[k]['Country'] = v
    
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-184-0b4a474be569>", line 2, in <module>
    D[k]['Country'] = v

KeyError: 0`

Comment: @spiff oooooooh. Jeez, you just need to do input_fwd['Country'] = countries['Country']

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 

`input_fwd['Country'] = countries['Country']

input_fwd.head()

      CCY Rating Tenor       CVA        Hurdle      Country
0  USDINR    AAA    1m  0.000000  0.000000e+00        Japan
1  USDINR    AAA    2m  0.000002  6.000000e-07  South Korea
2  USDINR    AAA    3m  0.000005  2.200000e-06    Singapore


input_fwd.tail()

          CCY  Rating Tenor       CVA    Hurdle Country
11755  EURGBP  Bminus    2Y  0.002339  0.004589     NaN
11756  EURGBP  Bminus    3Y  0.005822  0.008619     NaN`

I don't see how that would do it, but above is the output

Comment: @spiff dude, do you **really** expect me to try to parse your output like that? Why don't you explain exactly what it is you want. I thought you wanted a new column in `input_fwd` with all the countries cycling one after the other... apparently, you want something else. Clearly, this is an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem wrt the original question, so you should probably edit the title and add an *example of your desired output* along with your input. Usually that's the best approach.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  ok.. let me try to add input and desired output .. that would indeed be a much better approach here.. brb

Comment: @spiff OK I actually understand what you want now. BTW, the problem with your code was diagnosed a while back. I gave you the explanation earlier about objects, references, and copies. In your firs for-loop use `D["output_fwd_%s" % (countries['Country'][i])] = input_fwd.copy()`

Comment: input_fwd:
`  
col1 col2  col3
0  abc   1m    45
1  abc   2m    34
2  def   1m    23
3  def   2m    12
`
`countries['Country'] = ['Japan','South Korea','Singapore']`

output:
`
  col1 col2  col3      Country
0   abc   1m    45        Japan
1   abc   2m    34        Japan
2   def   1m    23        Japan
3   def   2m    12        Japan
4   abc   1m    45  South Korea
5   abc   2m    34  South Korea
6   def   1m    23  South Korea
7   def   2m    12  South Korea
8   abc   1m    45    Singapore
9   abc   2m    34    Singapore
10  def   1m    23    Singapore
11  def   2m.
`

Comment: @spiff and then to concat: `pd.concat(d for d in D.values())`

Comment: "now have keys for all the countries, which have the same data as input_fwd" - no, all your values *are* `input_fwd`. You've used a single object for every dict value.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga making it input_fwd.copy() does it.. thanks a lot once again with your patience.. I spent 2.5 hours on this... :( fml

edit: concat does the rest of the job